# Formatting time from seconds to HH:MM:SS in a countdown

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am having this simple countdown:

```
function offer_countdown_timer(countdown_start, countdown_time, update, complete) {
  var start = new Date(countdown_start).getTime();
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var now = countdown_time-(new Date().getTime()-start);
    if( now <= 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      complete();
    } else {
      update(Math.floor(now/1000));
    }
  },100); // the smaller this number, the more accurate the timer will be
}
```

and here I call it:

```
<script>
    offer_countdown_timer(
      '<%= s.created_at%>',
      3600000, // 1 hour in milliseconds
      function(timeleft) { // called every step to update the visible countdown
        var txt = timeleft+' seconds';
        $('#tender_countdown_<%= s.id %>').html(txt);
        //$('#tender_countdown_<%= s.id %>').html(moment(txt).format('HH:mm:ss'));        
        },
      function() {
        $('#product_<%= s.id %>').html('Offer has expired!');
      }
    );
</script>
```

Output of this is:

```
773 seconds
```

(and it's counting down)

I'd like to see something like this (HH:ss:mm):

```
00:12:53
```

(and counting it down).

I tried this to use this (with using the Moment.js lib - https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
$('#tender_countdown_<%= s.id %>').html(moment(txt).format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

But in this case, the output is this:

```
01:00:00
```

The time information is wrong, and it's not counting down. Why is that? How do I properly format the countdowning time?

Thank you

Comment: `txt` is a [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) not a date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of seconds is an abstract *duration* of time, rather than a date representing a specific *moment* in time. Moment's constructor expects you to give it a date string.

Moment has a Duration object which can parse your data. It doesn't have nice formatting functions yet, but you can construct the desired output easily enough:

```js
var txt = 773;
var m = moment.duration(txt, "s");
var output = m.hours() + ":" + m.minutes() + ":" + m.seconds();
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/ for more details.

Comment: I am just wondering - I am playing with the output and I get something like this: **0:20:9** - how do I set the format to **00:20:09**?

Comment: you'd have to pad the extra 0 yourself I think when you're creating the output, as the Duration functions can't do it for you (I heard they are working on a formatting function, but it's not around yet). So just check if the hour/minute/second is <10 and if so, pad another zero on the front.